# ¿Usando activerecord, qué tipo de query sería mas efectivo teniendo en cuenta 2 tablas en relación de uno a muchos?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rendimiento, activerecord

Tengo un escenario con 2 tablas relacionadas y quiero imprimir en pantalla en una lista información de ambas tablas.

**opción1.**

```
@data = User.where(id: [array_users_ids]).includes(:products)
```

**opción2.**

```
@data = User.where(id: [array_users_ids]).joins(:products).select('users.*, products.name as product_name')
```

Ahora lo que ocurre con la **opción1** es que genera en la consola una consulta sql por cada usuario con sus productos.

en cambio la **opción2** se traduce en un solo sql ejecutado.

He leido que la forma correcta de hacerlo sería con la **opción1** pero para mi no tiene sentido si la **opción2** genera una sola consulta sql y me trae la información correcta.

Comment: Si creas una query utilizando ActiveRecord y no especificas que atributos específicos son los que necesitas, entonces este hará un SELECT utilizando `*`, lo que evidentemente puede traer lo que necesitas, pero también lo que necesitas.

En terminos de eficiencia es recomendable siempre especificar cuales son los atributos necesarios, sin importar si son todos los atributos del modelo o no.

Comment: La primera es una mejor opción, ya que el incudes carga en memoria antes todos los products de x usuario y la consulta a la base de datos es menor, en esta consulta también puedes agregar el select para extraer la columna que necesitas.

La opción 2, carga la consulta de la bd utilizando la tabla asociada pero cuando extraigas datos de la tabla asociada esta te generará mas consutas

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas